# How can i order two tables?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, sql-order-by

**I have two** **tables** : `users ('ID' 'username' '...')` and `connectivities('ID' 'following_ID' '...')`

Each time one user follows another, an entry is created in `connectivities`. The followers are sorted in descending order after a query by user ID. Now I do not want to sort the followers by ID but by the entries in `connectivities`. So that always the last new follower is displayed first.

```
    public function getFollowers($offset = false,$limit = null){
    if (empty($this->user_id) || !is_numeric($this->user_id)) {
        return false;
    }

    else if (!empty($limit) && !is_numeric($limit)) {
        return false;
    }

    $user_id = $this->user_id;
    $t_users = T_USERS;
    $t_conn  = T_CONNECTIV;

    self::$db->join("{$t_conn} c","c.follower_id = u.user_id AND c.type = 1","INNER");
    self::$db->where("c.following_id",$user_id);
    self::$db->orderBy("u.user_id","DESC");

    if (!empty($offset) && is_numeric($offset)) {
        self::$db->where("u.user_id",$offset,'<');
    }

    $users = self::$db->get("{$t_users} u",$limit);
    $data  = array();

    foreach ($users as $key => $user_data) {
        $user_data = $this->userData($user_data);
        $user_data->is_following = false;

        if (IS_LOGGED) {
            $this->user_id = self::$me->user_id;
            $user_data->is_following = $this->isFollowing($user_data->user_id);
        }

        $data[]    = $user_data;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

If I have changed `self :: $ db-> orderBy ("u.user_id", "DESC");` to `self :: $ db-> orderBy ("c.id", "DESC");`  that works as well but always the same ex 20 entries are displayed. 
These are then always repeated. I think the problem is the offset.

Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do here. Perhaps you can provide a sample dataset and how you want it sorted?

Comment: I want to sort the query by the table 'connectivities' by ID DESC. This works so far when i change the line to orderBy ("c.id", "DESC") but only for approximately 20 entries

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to sort it by both user id and follower id at the same time, no? Sort by users first, then sort by each user's followers?

Answer (score 0):

invoke `$db->orderBy` twice, to sort rows by `u.userid desc, c.id desc`

```
self::$db->join("{$t_conn} c","c.follower_id = u.user_id AND c.type = 1","INNER");
self::$db->where("c.following_id",$user_id);
self::$db->orderBy("u.user_id desc","c.id desc");
```